# Show that if $p,q$ prime, $p<q$, and $p\not\mid q-1$, then there is $L:\mathbb{F}_q$ which is a splitting field for each $x^p-a,a\in\mathbb{F}_q^*$.

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

I'm working my way through the exercises in a book on Galois theory. Right now I've got one exercise left in the chapter on finite fields before I continue to the next chapter. But for this one, I need clarification on what the exercise is even asking! See the title of the post for the exercise.

Is it that taking $L$ to be a splitting field for one of the polynomials, for example $x^p - 1$, gives a splitting field for each of the polynomials $x^p - a, a \in \mathbb{F}_q^*$?

Comment: It may be helpful to note that if $f(x)$ is a degree $k$ irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_q$, then the splitting field for $f(x)$ is $\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: Thanks, I'm also noticing now that with $\langle c \rangle = \mathbb{F}_q^*$, a splitting field $L$ for $x^p - c$ would introduce a $p^\text{th}$ root $\gamma \in L$ of $c$ with $\gamma^p = c$. Since $(\gamma^k)^p = (\gamma^p)^k = c^k, 1 \le k \le q - 1$, $p^\text{th}$ roots of $a \in \mathbb{F}_q^*$ are actually introduced.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my question about what the exercise is asking, yes, the goal is to take $L$ to be a splitting field for any one of the polynomials and then show $L$ is, in fact, a splitting field for each of the polynomials $x^p - a, a \in \mathbb{F}_q^*$. I've reached this decision because I've been able to put together a proof. Please verify!

Write $\langle c \rangle = \mathbb{F}_q^*.$ Then $\langle c^p \rangle = \langle c \rangle = \mathbb{F}_q^*$ since $p \not\mid q - 1.$ Thus $\mathbb{F}_q^*$ contains a $p^\text{th}$ root of each element in $\mathbb{F}_q^*.$

Take $L:\mathbb{F}_q^*$ to be a splitting field for $x^p - 1.$ Then $L$ introduces all the $p^\text{th}$ roots of unity, $1, \omega_1, \dots, \omega_{p - 1}.$ But then $L$ also introduces all the $p^\text{th}$ roots of $a \in \mathbb{F}_q^*, c^k, c^k\omega_1, \dots, c^k\omega_{p - 1}$ for some $k, 1 \le k \le q - 1.$

Conversely, a splitting field for $x^p - a, a \in \mathbb{F}_q^*$ introduces all the $p^\text{th}$ roots of unity by dividing by $c^k \in \mathbb{F}_q^*.$

Therefore, $L$ is a splitting field for each $x^p - a, a \in \mathbb{F}_q^*.$